# Google Cloud Platform adding OAuth Client ID says Requested entity already exists

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth, google-fitness-api

I created a OAuth 2 client Id in Google Cloud Platform(GCP) in our production application. However this was only for internal use, so I removed it and tried to add it again in our development GCP project.

However when trying to add it, it says

```
Save failed
Requested entity already exists

Tracking number: xxx
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to do some extra steps to completely remove the OAuth 2 client id? I removed them around a month ago already, so it really should be gone by now.

Comment: Have you tried steps described [here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?authuser=0#zippy=)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems after 1 month the problem has automatically resolved itself. I assume it just soft deletes when you press delete, and then hard deletes one month later. Pretty annoying system.

You can also remove the entire project to get rid of unwanted ghost clients, but obviously you then lose all configuration.

Comment: Super annoying. Wish they had a button that was like, "ARE YOU SURE? THIS DELETES IT PERMANENTLY!"